# Optimization of utility function with Lagrange multiplier

Tags: optimization, economics, lagrange-multiplier

Let u: ${\mathbf R^n_+ \rightarrow \mathbf R}$ be a utility function of n goods which you buy in quantities $x_1,…,x_n$ to the prices $p_1,…,p_n$ under the budget K. So maximize $u(x_1,…,x_n)$ subject to the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i k_i=K$. Let L be the Lagrangian of this problem. Show that we have a solution to the optimization whenever $\nabla L = \mathbf 0$ (Use concavity of the utility function).
For a given K let $V(K)$ be this maximum and let $\lambda (K)$ be the langrange multiplier. Show that $V'(K)=\lambda(K)$

I don't really get it. I mean you normally solve this by putting $\nabla L = \mathbf 0$ and solve the equations. Is the point of the exercise to prove the lagrange multiplier theorem? And the rest I can't figure out how to write $V(K)$. Help out a lost economist:)

Answer (score 0):

So a few hints:

Firstly, let $x^*_i(K)$ be the optimal quantities of each good to consume at buget level $K$.  Then $V(K)$ is simply:

$$V(K)= \max_x \; \mathcal{L}(x,K) = u(x_1^*(K), ... , x_n^*(K))$$

Second, keep in the back of your mind the [Envelope Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_theorem).

Finally, bear in mind the intuition behind indirect utility functions.

If you're truly stuck, a good worked version of this problem and explanation of the full intuition can be found [here](http://www.sfu.ca/~wainwrig/Econ331/env-theorem2.pdf), in particular section 1.3.

Hope this helps!